# Match values of multiple columns within an ID

Tags: python, pandas

**Sample DF:**

```
ID     Match1        Match2        Match3     Match4       Match5
1      Yes           No            Yes        Yes          Yes
2      Yes           No            Yes        Yes          No
2      Yes           No            No         Yes          Yes
3      No            Yes           Yes        Yes          No
3      No            Yes           No         No           No
4      Yes           No            Yes        No           No
4      Yes           No            Yes        Yes          Yes
```

**Expected DF:**

```
 ID     Match1     Match2        Match3     Match4    Match5 Final_Match
    1      Yes      No            Yes        Yes      Yes     Clear
    2      Yes      No            Yes        Yes      No      Unclear
    2      Yes      No            No         Yes      Yes     Unclear
    3      No       Yes           Yes        Yes      No      Clear
    3      No       Yes           No         No       No      Unclear
    4      Yes      No            Yes        No       No      Unclear
    4      Yes      No            Yes        Yes      Yes     Clear
```

**Problem Statement:**

1. If ID is non-repetitive simply put `Clear` in `Final_Match` column (Example ID 1)
2. If the ID's are repetitive then within an ID count `Yes` in Match1 to Match5 columns, whichever has greater "Yes" put `Clear` for that one and `Unclear` for the other (Example ID 3 & 4
3. If the ID's are repetitive then within an ID count `Yes` in Match1 to Match5 columns,if they have equal "Yes" put `Unclear` in both (Example ID 2)

**I couldn't find anything on how to solve within ID ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also achieve this by using `Groupby.rank`:

```
# Helper Series
s = (df.replace({'Yes': 1, 'No': 0})
     .iloc[:, 1:]
     .sum(1))

df['final_match'] = np.where(s.groupby(df['ID']).rank(ascending=False).eq(1), 'Clear', 'Unclear')
```

Comment: I am now trying your solution by putting two columns in Group by conditions, I am getting a "Key error" although I have both those columns in by dataframe

Comment: can you post your groupby statement here?

Comment: `np.where(s.groupby(df['Supplier_Name_Translated','Spent']).rank(ascending=False).eq(1), 'Full Match','Partial Match')`

Comment: The change is it is now not by "ID" column as before but two other columns, one of which is text and other is numbers

Comment: Tried, gives this error `ValueError: Grouper for '<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>' not 1-dimensional`

Comment: Got this error `TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed`

Comment: Sorry, I mis-typed the last suggestion, can you try: `np.where(s.groupby([df['Supplier_Name_Translated'], df['Spent']]).rank(ascending=False).eq(1), 'Full Match','Partial Match')` ?

Comment: My `Spent` column was string floats, I converted in to int also. but still getting new error `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable`

Comment: Are there any `NaN` in `Spent` now?

Comment: I checked that, there is no 'NaN' or blanks for that matter

Answer (score 2):

Another way of doing this would be:

```
df['sum_yes']=df.iloc[:,1:6].eq('Yes').sum(axis=1)
df['final']=df.groupby('ID')['sum_yes'].transform\
             (lambda x: np.where((x==x.max())&(~x.duplicated(keep=False)),'Clear','Unclear'))
print(df)

   ID Match1 Match2 Match3 Match4 Match5  sum_yes    final
0   1    Yes     No    Yes    Yes    Yes        4    Clear
1   2    Yes     No    Yes    Yes     No        3  Unclear
2   2    Yes     No     No    Yes    Yes        3  Unclear
3   3     No    Yes    Yes    Yes     No        3    Clear
4   3     No    Yes     No     No     No        1  Unclear
5   4    Yes     No    Yes     No     No        2  Unclear
6   4    Yes     No    Yes    Yes    Yes        4    Clear
```

**P.S** You can drop the `sum_yes` column if you want.

Comment: If i have columns in between these Match columns or any other columns left or right to news `Match` columns, do I need to change the `iloc[:,1:6]` part ?

Comment: @RahulAgarwal yes, then you can use the `filter()` method and like=Match as Chris's solution shows. :)

Answer (score 1):

Using `pandas.DataFrame.groupby`:

```
final_match = []
for i, d in df.groupby('ID'):
    if len(d) == 1:
        final_match.append('Clear')
    else:
        counter = (d.filter(like='Match') == 'Yes').sum(1)
        if counter.nunique() == 1:
            final_match.extend(['Unclear'] * len(d))
        else:
            final_match.extend(counter.apply(lambda x: 'Clear' if x == max(counter) else 'Unclear').tolist())
df['final_match'] = final_match

print(df)
   ID Match1 Match2 Match3 Match4 Match5 final_match
0   1    Yes     No    Yes    Yes    Yes       Clear
1   2    Yes     No    Yes    Yes     No     Unclear
2   2    Yes     No     No    Yes    Yes     Unclear
3   3     No    Yes    Yes    Yes     No       Clear
4   3     No    Yes     No     No     No     Unclear
5   4    Yes     No    Yes     No     No     Unclear
6   4    Yes     No    Yes    Yes    Yes       Clear
```

Explanation:

- `len(d) == 1`: if non-repetitive, add `Clear`
- `counter = (d.filter(like='Match') == 'Yes').sum(1)`: Counts the number of 'Yes' in each column
- `counter.nunique() == 1`: if all rows have the same number of 'Yes's, then all are marked as 'Unclear'
- `counter.apply(lambda x: 'Clear' if x == max(counter) else 'Unclear').tolist()`: if rows have different counts of 'Yes', mark the highest with 'Clear', rest with 'Unclear'

Comment: The problem is where ID is only coming once.when I run part of the code the final_match shows `Clear` but when I run the whole code it replaces `Clear` with `Unclear`